# How do I make a java program to find the largest variable in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

I'm working on a project for class and I'm struggling a bit. I'm trying to find the largest number in an array provided with command line arguments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No numbers were provided in the command line.");
    } else {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int[] n = new int[a];

        double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (n[i] > max) {
                max = n[i];
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + n[i]);

    }
}
```

It would be super helpful if someone could point out what's wrong. Thx :)

Comment: You made a new empty array. Specifically, `n`

Comment: What is your command line input?

Comment: It's just a list of integers. For this specifically its 5 70 90 8 7. It's supposed to pick out the largest being 90.

Comment: Your code just parses the first argument, and then creates an empty array.

Comment: the code is supposed to check `i < n.length` instead of `i < a`

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the args, because you are using the new empty array n, which you have created.

You need to use input args as below:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No numbers were provided in the command line.");
    } else {
        double max = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            final double currentIndexValue = Double.parseDouble(args[i]);
            if (currentIndexValue > max) {
                max = currentIndexValue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum: " + max);
    }
}
```

I have used double here, as you used originally double. But I think you should use int, if only integer is provided as input always.

Comment: I have improved it for two things: (1) Corrected unnecessary boxing and unboxing (2) Start with the first element as `max` and then compare `max` with the rest of the numbers.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for the updates. Agreed, that was unnecessary boxing and unboxing.